# How to download KML of layers used on this website map?

Tags: kml

https://www.huduser.gov/portal/sadda/sadda_qct.html
I am trying to get the KML file for 2022 Difficult Development Areas and 2022 Qualified Census Tracts. Can I somehow get the KML file using the source code?

Comment: no KML but maptiles like https://map2.huduser.gov/mapcache/gmaps/DDA2022Boundary@GoogleMapsCompatible/7/27/49.png

Answer (score 1):

On the website you have provided link to they say:

> The 2022 Qualified Census Tracts (QCTs) and Difficult Development
> Areas (DDAs) are effective January 1, 2022. The 2022 designations use
> data from the 2010 Decennial census. The designation methodology is
> explained in the federal Register notice published September 9, 2021

You have two options to obtain underlying data which can be found by following their links on the website:

1. use their hudgis-hud.opendata.arcgis.com - they have both *Difficult Development Areas* and *Qualified Census Tracts* data there available for download in multitude of formats including KML
2. use the rest service by adding to your GIS software like ArcPro or QGIS their underlying services address https://services.arcgis.com/VTyQ9soqVukalItT/ArcGIS/rest/services/

Without reading through methodology I am not sure what do they do to display *2022 version* from the underlaying data, sorry.